# Numerically integrate and plot $f(x;p)$ for a range of the parameter $p$

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

Suppose we have an integral of the form $$I = \int_a^b dx \, \sin(px), \tag{1}$$ where I've take $f(x;p) = \sin (px)$ to be specific. I want to plot this integral for a range of values of the parameter $10<p<100$ say. How can one do that? Please notice that the function $f$ is in reality kind of **complicated** and the integral must be done using **numerical integration**.

Comment: You might consider using `FunctionInterpolation[]` for the purpose.

Comment: `ListPlot[ NIntegrate[f[x,#],{x,a,b}]&/@Range[10,100] ]`

Comment: @N.J.Evans So you first define `f[{x,p}]:= Sin[p*x]` (say) and then write 
`ListPlot[ NIntegrate[f[x,#],{x,a,b}]&/@Range[10,100] ]`?

Comment: Yes, but you need to make sure the brackets are the same when you define `f[x_,p_]` and when you use it. Either one works, but your definition would make me think that x and p typically come together in a list.

Comment: @N.J.Evans OK so the number icon `#` means with respect to the second variable because it appears in the second position in the argument of `f`? Now I've managed to plot my function actually but I want to be sure what it is I've plotted, i.e. if it is wrt to the "second-position" variable (I mean there are no other variables around so it must be but anyway).

Comment: Just for the record: ListPlot was unreliable and slow in my case. The accepted solution (NIntegrate and then Plot) was much better (and faster) for my case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define:

```
integ[p_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f[x, p], {x, a, b}]
```

Then plot it:

```
Plot[integ[p],{p,10,100}]
```

Comment: Hey @Ivan, what if $p$ is a not a integer? Can we do the same but with smaller step-sizes, say 0.01?

Comment: @Love, nothing Ivan did here assumes that `p` is an integer. He did forget the safety mechanism of `integ[p_?NumericQ] := (* stuff*)` tho.

Comment: OK I assumed `integ[]` had something to do with integers.

Comment: Ops, just noticed that integ is just a name haha sorry

Comment: @LoveLearning `integ` is for integral lol

Comment: Haha yeah I noticed that after

Comment: Now that I've used your method and compare with the other ones (ListPlot etc...) I must say that this one was far better for my problem at hand. Great job! @Ivan

Comment: @CosmeFulanito Thanks for this solution! It works with two-variable functions as well: `integ[p_,q_?NumericQ]:=NIntegrate[f[x,p,q],{x,a,b}];` followed by `DensityPlot[integ[p,q],{p,10,100},{q,20,200}]` (or `Plot3D[...]`).