# Plot the result of NIntegrate for different parameter values

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, parametric-functions

I want to plot the result of a numerical integration containing a parameter in terms of the parameter. The code is:

```
 δ= 0-10^10
 ω = 10^10
 γ = 5*10^12
 ϵ = 10^10
 Λ = 10^12
 Z = 5*10^12
 Δ = 10^8
A = N[ArcTan[((δ-γ)/ω)]]
B = N[ArcTan[((δ+γ)/ω)]]
F = -(ω/2)Cos[A](1 +((δ-γ)/ω)^2)
G = -(ω/2)Cos[B](1+((δ+γ)/ω)^2) 

f=2 Δ^2 Sin[(A + B)/2]^2 Re[NIntegrate[E^(-i t((2ϵ+F+G)/Λ))
E^(-(Z/Λ)(t ArcTan[t]-(Log[1+t^2]/2))), {t, 0, ∞}]]
```

The parameter is `δ`. I want to plot `f` versus `δ`. How should I do this?

Comment: I don't see you using `NDSolve[]` anywhere in your code.

Comment: The imaginary unit is represented by uppercase `I` in *Mathematica*. Is your definition of `delta` supposed to represent a range?

Comment: @J. M. I think that `NIntegrate[]` is equevalent to `NDSolve`.

Comment: No, no it's not. Even a quick look at the documentation will show the differences.

Comment: @J. M. Yes. You are absolutely right. I corrected the title.

Comment: Potential duplicates: [(70196)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/70196), [(85459)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85459)

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[δ, f];
f := 2 Δ^2 Sin[(A + B)/2]^2 Re@NIntegrate[ E^(-I t (2 ϵ + F +  G)/Λ)
                               E^(-Z/Λ (t ArcTan@t- Log[1 + t^2]/2)), {t, 0, ∞}]

Plot[f, {δ, 0, 100}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]